# Create new local server in pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have PostgreSQL 11 and PGadmin 4 installed on windows. Currently I'm connected to a AWS server which hosts all of my data.

I want to create a local server (localhost) as a testing environment where I can experiment. I can't seem to do it though, and the other similar questions on stack don't help. Here's what my process is:

1. in pgAdmin, right click 'Servers' and go Create>Server
2. On the 'Create - Server' pop up box, i type in Name: Localserver. For 'connection' I type localhost. Port I leave as default '5432', db: postgres, username: postgres password: empty
3. click save.

however, I get an error:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>   Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>   Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

[image: screenshot of error message]

What should I do? I am the admin if that makes a difference.

Comment: why @Grogu answer not accepted?

Comment: @doc because Grogu talks about setting Postrges up from scratch. I only ask about creating localhost after installing pgAdmin.

Answer (score 99):

As a new Postgres user, I did not understand how to make use of Postgres on Ubuntu. So I'm just going to chime in and help out other newbies who perhaps cannot figure out how to work with Postgres on Linux. If you're using Windows, steps should be similar.

Before you get to using PgAdmin, a bit of configuration is required. Most will happen in your terminal at first.

Open a terminal using `Ctrl + Alt + T` if you're on a PC. Or just pres `ALT + F1` and begin typing Terminal.

> Let's start with the basics first and make sure you have proper
> installation.

## 1. Installing Postgres Latest

**1.1 update the system software packages**

```
sudo apt update
```

**1.2 install latest version of PostgreSQL from default Ubuntu repositories**

```
sudo apt install postgresql
```

> the installer will create a new PostgreSQL collection of databases
> that will be managed by a single server instance

**Default data directory :**  `/var/lib/postgresql/your-version/main`

**Configurations files :** `/etc/postgresql/your-version/main`

## 2. Checking if Postgres Service is Installed

**2.1 Check if Postgres is Active**

```
sudo systemctl is-active postgresql
```

You should see : active

**2.2 Check if Postgres is enabled**

```
sudo systemctl is-enabled postgresql
```

You should see : enabled

**2.3 Check Postgres Service status**

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

You should see : **active (exited)** marked in green

**2.4 Check if Postgres is ready to accept connections**

```
sudo pg_isready
```

You should see : /var/run/postgresql:5432 - accepting connections

## 3. Configuring Postgres Authentication

**3.1 Opening the pg_hba.conf as SUPERUSER**

```
sudo code --user-data-dir=~/root /etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf
```

I'm using visual studio code so for me code is vsc codename. If you're using vim or sublime just replace code with your text editor name.

**3.2 Configuring pg_hba.conf**

> Notes: you shouldn't need to change anything here, just make sure your
> configuration files matches the following lines :

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Hit save and close.

**3.3 Restart Postgres Service**

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

## 4. Create NEW Server

> For me, this is where all my confusion was. Before you use PgAdmin,
> you need to create a server in your terminal, then you can connect and
> manager it with PgAdmin just like you would with PhpMyAdmin. It's
> actually easier.

**4.1 Access the PostgreSQL database shell**

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
```

You will then see this : `postgres=#`

**4.2 Creating new server and user**

```
postgres=# create user bob with superuser password 'admin';
```

That's how you create new user and server in Postgres. Let's move on to PgAdmin.

## 5. Installing pgAdmin4

**5.1 Add public key for the repository**

```
curl https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo apt-key add
```

> Notes : if you don't have curl your Ubuntu will give you the command to install it

**5.2 create the repository configuration file**

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'
```

**5.3 install pgAdmin4**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

**5.4 run the web setup script installed with the pgadmin4 binary package**

```
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```

> It will asks you for your email address and password. This email and
> password is required to login to the PgAdmin4 web interface

## 6. Accessing pgAdmin4 Web Interface

**6.1 Open your favorite browser**

type in the address of the PgAdmin web interface. It usually looks like this

`http://127.0.0.1/pgadmin4`

> Note : After installation the web setup script will tell you exactly
> where to access the web interface.

When you see the login screen, enter the email and password you've chosen during the web setup script.

**6.2 Adding New Server Connection**

6.2.1 Click on **Add New Server**

6.2.2 Under **General tab** enter a name for your server. ANY name you would like, it doesn't matter. You could enter `PgServer1` or whatever. Don't change anything else.

6.2.3 Switch to **Connection Tab**

```
Hostname/ Address : localhost
Port : 5432
Maintenance database : postgres (always)
Username :  **bob** (the username youve chosen at 4.2)
Password : admin (or any password you chose at 4.2)
```

Hit Save.

Voila! You should be connected successfully. If not, just open terminal and create a new user like we did at 4.2

> Notes : to create databases is very easy just right click on your
> servername

```
create > databases
```

## Useful Resources & Tutorials

[PostgreSQL Fundamentals](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/) : Queries and the likes

[PostgreSQL & JSON](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/) : useful for dealing with JS apps

[PostgreSQL & Nodejs](https://node-postgres.com) : Create realtime apps with nodejs and socket.io

**More PostgreSQL Nodejs**

- https://github.com/supabase/realtime
- https://whatsyourssn.com/posts/real-time-app-socket-postgresql/

## UPDATE 2023

While following my own tutorial I ran into certificate issues at step 5  when I tried to create the repository file. The full error I was getting was [this](https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/5722).

I want to post the solution that worked for me [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095266/apt-get-update-failed-because-certificate-verification-failed-because-handshake).

Comment: Thorough and informative. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you, I was having a hard time configuring it on Ubuntu

Comment: I did everything as described above (except pgadmin installation) when creating a server I get the error 'connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "bob"'
How can I fix this?

Comment: @Marseille : You say you did everything "except this one thing" and you wonder why its not working? Try everything :)

Answer (score 14):

This is probably one of two things.

1. You have set up a Postgres server, but have not adjusted `listen_addresses` in your postgresql.conf file, or
2. You have not set up a Postgres server on your local machine. ("Create Server" is a bit misleading, it should probably be "Create Server Connection".)

Comment: ah ok thank you for your answer. Can you give me any advice on what to do in each case?

1. i don't have postgresql.conf I have postgres.conf.sample

2. potentially, but i'm not sure how to set this up. I though it was set up automatically on installing PostgreSQL...

Comment: Sure, happy to help.  What OS are you on?

Comment: @Chirs Curvey I ended up uninstalling pgadmin, postgresql and then installing it again, but creating a local server in the process. AFTER that I then connected to my my AWS databases.

Comment: @ChrisCurvey I would still like to know how to do this on Windows.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140258/create-pgadmin-database-on-local-machine

Comment: @ChrisCurvey Hi! can you help me a little bit with some questions about the creation of new server connection please?

Comment: @Programmer89 your best option is to just ask your question.  Someone here will get to it.

Answer (score 3):

Usually a “connection refused” error indicates that the database server is either 1) not running, or 2) configured in such a way that it is not listening to the right port or IP address. Be sure to check `ps -ef` to see if Postgres is running, and also look at `postgresql.conf` to see if `port` and `listen_addresses` are set properly.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the postgres service is running.
example in Linux : `systemctl enable postgresql.service`

Comment: Hi Rakshit, if the postgres service is running, the steps taken by the OP should work with nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

Why? Attempting to connect to the server that is not running.

Action: Start your PostgreSQL server.

The path in the command below points to the data directory configured during the installation of PostgreSQL. Run this in Windows cmd.

```
pg_ctl -D "C:\user\PostgreSQL\data" start

>server started
```

After this go to pgAdmin and follow the initial steps as in question.

1. Create Server
2. Under General: Name: mytestServer
3. Under Connection: Hostname: localhost, Password: yourPassword,
   keep other settings as default
4. Hit save

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't, then first install the Postgres server on your machine. For windows, this is the currently active link for downloading the installation package: https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

As other answers here pointed out, PgAdmin is only a interface for using the Postgres server. Once you install the server locally, you'll be able to see the server on the left hand side pane after restarting PgAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is struggling to login - Here is the caveat - Actually default username for the postgres sql is your username and database is postgres - So running this command `psql -U <username> -d postgres` would do the trick